# Inserting/Updating MongoDB Collection in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have created a for loop in python which goes through a prediction collection in MongoDB, and checks whether there is a row containing the same student ID and todays date. If there is, it should update the row, if there isn't it should insert the row. Below is my code:

```
def getPredictions(school):
    schoolDB = DB[school['database']['name']]
    schoolPredictions = schoolDB['session_attendance_predicted']
    Predictions = schoolPredictions.aggregate([{
        '$project': {
            'school': '$school',
            'student':'$student',
            'dateUploaded':'$date',
            'probability':'$probability'
        }        
    }])
    return list(Predictions)

Predictions = getPredictions(school)
Predictions = pd.DataFrame(Predictions)

for i in df.index:
    student = df.loc[i,'students']
    dateToday = date.today()
    probabilityOfLowerThanThreshold = 100       
    dateToday = datetime.datetime.combine(dateToday, datetime.time(0, 0))

    MongoRow = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'school': {'1': schoolID}, 'student': {'1': student}, 'dateUploaded': {'1': dateToday}, 'probability': {'1': probabilityOfLowerThanThreshold}})
    data_dict = MongoRow.to_dict()

    schoolDB = DB[school['database']['name']]
    collection = schoolDB['session_attendance_predicted']

    for i in Predictions.index:
          collection.replace_one({'student': {'1': student}, 'dateUploaded': {'1': dateToday}}, data_dict, upsert=True)
```

However, it isn't working. It isn't producing anything in the database at all, so Predictions collection is empty. I want to insert the data_dict row if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, then just update it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: My guess is your not hitting the `replace_one` line. Also there isn't enough code there to work out the issue. We'd need to see where you set `student`, `dateToday`, and `Predictions.index`

Comment: @Belly Buster, I have added in the extra code requested. Thanks

Comment: Your making a mighty meal of this. Why are you taking data from mongo, putting it into a dataframe just to then update mongo again. What is the dataframe giving you? can you just try and explain in real simple terms what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Belly Buster I want to add the MongoRow dataframe into the mongo DB collection. However if a row already exists in the collection with the same date and student, then just update it with the new probability and school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This self-contained code sample will hopefully get you most of the way there. The first time you run it it will create a record from the dataframe; the second time it will update it.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import datetime

DB = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Seed some test data
data = [['5beee5678d62101c9c4e7dbb', '5bf3e06f9a892068705d8420', '2020-03-27', 0.000038],
        ['5beee5678d62101c9c4e7dbc', '5bf3e06f9a892068705d8421', '2020-03-26', 0.000037]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['school', 'student', 'date', 'Probability'])

for rowindex, row in df.iterrows():
    record = row.to_dict()
    record['date'] = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(0, 0))
    DB.session_attendance_predicted.replace_one({'student': row.get('student'), 'date': record['date']}, record, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do a bulk upsert instead of iterating through the rows, to make it faster?